# Creating an if then clause in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, concat

I'm fairly new to SQL and I am am used to writing formulas in Crystal Reports.

I want to recreate the following formula from Crystal Reports into an SQL statement to create a column:

```
if (not isnull ({OT.TITLE})) and (not isnull ({OA.LASTNAME}))then {OA.LASTNAME}& ", "& {OT.TITLE} else
if (not isnull ({OT.TITLE})) and (isnull ({OA.LASTNAME}))then {OT.TITLE} else ""
```

I created the following statement, but it only works if the title and last name fields are both filled out. Otherwise there is an unnecessary ,:

```
SELECT concat(OA.Lastname, ', ', OT.Title)
FROM OA
LEFT JOIN OT 
    ON OT.ObjectID = OA.ObjectID
```

Basically I need a column that shows the Last name and title separated by a comma. If there is no Last name, then show the title. If there is no title then show nothing, even if there is a last name.

I would really appreciate any help you can give me. I am unfortunately working with SQL 2014.

Comment: What if there a `Lastname` but no `Title`?...show just the `Lastname` or show nothing?

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 2):

Something like ?

```
SELECT *
       ,CASE 
            WHEN (OT.TITLE IS NOT NULL AND OA.LASTNAME IS NOT NULL) 
            THEN OA.LASTNAME+','+OT.TITLE
            WHEN (OT.TITLE IS NOT NULL AND OA.LASTNAME IS NULL) 
            THEN OT.TITLE
            ELSE ''
        END as colname
    FROM OA
    LEFT JOIN OT ON OT.ObjectID = OA.ObjectID
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, I used the statement you suggested and it unfortunately doesn't return a result if there is a title but no last name. The result is also presented in a format I haven't seen before. It is a table but uses ----------- instead of solid lines:
colname
----------- 
(0 Zeilen betroffen)

I am not quite sure why.

Comment: I resolved the issue with the table format.

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it. Try this in your existing code as well:

```
SELECT concat(iif(OA.Lastname is not null,OA.Lastname+ ',',''),OT.Title)
    FROM OA LEFT JOIN OT ON OT.ObjectID = OA.ObjectID
```

The IIF syntax is: `IIF( boolean_expression, true_value, false_value )`

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I tried out the statement and it worked unless there is a title but no last name. In this case I would like the title to be shown on its own.